# Difference between fonts-liberation and fonts-liberation2 packages?

Tags: fonts

I can see that package fonts-liberation has extra Narrow fonts compared to fonts-liberation.  Does anyone know what is the history of these two packages, and why they are different?  Is fonts-liberation2 newer or older?

**fonts-liberation package:**

https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/fonts-liberation/filelist

**fonts-liberation2 package:**

https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/fonts-liberation2/filelist

Comment: Read the changelog for a start : http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/f/fonts-liberation2/fonts-liberation2_2.00.1-5_changelog and http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/f/fonts-liberation/fonts-liberation_1.07.2-6_changelog . It appears liberation2 is an update of liberation 1 and that the updates in 2 are not in 1 .

Comment: Thank you for linking these.  Using the change log, I checked out bug Debian 699322 (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=699322) where the following explanation is given:  
'the plan is to fork off the current packaging twice and package the new upstream version in one branch and the sans-narrow font of the current package in the other one (as "fonts-liberation-sans-narrow") while keeping upstream patches on par with liberation-fonts'

Comment: Great, post that as an answer and link the bug report =)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, why don't you post it as an answer.  It was your response that led me to the bug report, so you deserve the credit! :)

Comment: because it was just a nudge, you did the hard work, I merely suggested where you start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upstream (newest) version is packaged in `fonts-liberation2` and does not contain the narrow fonts.  At some point in the future the remaining fonts will be available a new package named `fonts-liberation-sans-narrow`.

**Debian Bug #699322**

This explanation is given Debian bug #699322 (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=699322):

*'...the plan is to fork off the current packaging twice and package the new upstream version in one branch and the sans-narrow font of the current package in the other one (as "fonts-liberation-sans-narrow") while keeping upstream patches on par with liberation-fonts.'*

This bug was referenced in the changelog for fonts-liberation2 package.

**Change log for fonts-liberation package:**

http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/f/fonts-liberation/fonts-liberation_1.07.2-6_changelog

**Change log for fonts-liberation2 package:**

http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/f/fonts-liberation2/fonts-liberation2_2.00.1-5_changelog